# how to intercept, process, and then send audio to app?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, voice

I want to create a real time voice modulator with the audio output from the modulator going to an app or video game on Windows 10.  The concept is the same as [MorphVox](https://store.steampowered.com/app/269470/MorphVOX_Pro__Voice_Changer/) and [VoiceMod](https://www.voicemod.net/free-voice-changer-software/).  It looks like MorphVox creates a virtual device and it looks like VoiceMod is also using a virtual audio device. I would like to know where to start.  I would really like some help finding a starting point to making a virtual audio device.  Any language is fine if someone is willing to show code (if it can be achieved in more than one language).  But I'd be happy with a good tutorial also!  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: zero in on notion of `audio loopback device`

Comment: Yeah I've checked those out. Like VAC and what not. But is there any that have an exposed API or CLI off the top of your head? I'm wanting to make it where the user only needs to use the application I will make without needing to configure the loopback externally.

Comment: this level of detail is highly OS specific ... not aware of a high level api however given sufficient time and effort those settings are controllable ...  alt approach would be to tap into the audio flow at application level which will be far easier ...

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I was thinking I could create a virtual audio device using DirectShow.  But the docs are somewhat confusing for me. I mean I'll go through it a lot until I get it.  I just needed to know if that's where I should be looking and if someone is generous a Kickstarter with some code lol.